# DC Cell + Copper Wire + Ground Water

Tags: electrolysis

DC Cell + Copper Wire + Ground Water produces bubbles from wire and water turns rust red gradually? What is happening?

I can see something is settling down...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groundwater contain besides other things $\ce{Fe^2+}$ a lot of organic material [Lenntech](http://www.lenntech.com/groundwater/properties.htm), [Natural Variations in the Composition of Groundwater](http://library.state.or.us/repository/2010/201008250826323/index.pdf). Oxygen released during electrolysis denatures organic proteins and the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ oxidize to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ that resulting to the reddish colorization.

Comment: It also lookes like the copper wire is dissolving!!